# Android Face Detection API - Stored video file

Tags: android, video, face-detection, android-vision

I would like to perform face detection / tracking on a video file (e.g. an MP4 from the users gallery) using the Android Vision `FaceDetector` API. I can see many examples on using the [CameraSource](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/CameraSource) class to perform face tracking on the stream coming directly from the camera (e.g. [on the android-vision github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/facetracker/FaceTrackerActivity.java)), but nothing on video files.

I tried looking at the source code for `CameraSource` through Android Studio, but it is obfuscated, and I couldn't see the original online. I image there are many commonalities between using the camera and using a file. Presumably I just play the video file on a `Surface`, and then pass that to a pipeline.

Alternatively I can see that `Frame.Builder` has functions `setImageData` and `setTimestampMillis`. If I was able to read in the video as `ByteBuffer`, how would I pass that to the `FaceDetector` API? I guess [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33173525/android-vision-face-detection-with-video-stream) is similar, but no answers. Similarly, decode the video into `Bitmap` frames and pass that to `setBitmap`.

Ideally I don't want to render the video to the screen, and the processing should happen as fast as the `FaceDetector` API is capable of.

Comment: There's an open source version of CameraSource here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java

Comment: Did you solve your problem, I am facing the same?

Answer (score 2):

> Alternatively I can see that Frame.Builder has functions setImageData and setTimestampMillis. If I was able to read in the video as ByteBuffer, how would I pass that to the FaceDetector API?

Simply call `SparseArray<Face> faces = detector.detect(frame);` where `detector` has to be created like this:

```
FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
   .setProminentFaceOnly(true)
   .build();
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to take a video file and generate the right kind of ByteBuffer for the FaceDetector API? Or can you point me to a link? The SO question I mentioned (33173525) was having issues converting their data into the correct buffer format (ImageFormat.YV12), and has no solution posted.

Comment: MediaCodec API is the "official" way of doing such things now. It's overcomplicated though. Maybe you will have more success with ffmpeg libraries, but I would rather use MediaCodec.

Answer (score 1):

If processing time is not an issue, using `MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime` solves the question. As Anton suggested, you can also use `FaceDetector.detect`:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
Frame frame;
SparseArray<Face> faces;
MediaMetadataRetriever mMMR = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mMMR.setDataSource(videoPath);
String timeMs = mMMR.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION); // video time in ms
int totalVideoTime= 1000*Integer.valueOf(timeMs); // total video time, in uS
for (int time_us=1;time_us<totalVideoTime;time_us+=deltaT){
        bitmap = mMMR.getFrameAtTime(time_us, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC); // extract a bitmap element from the closest key frame from the specified time_us
        if (bitmap==null) break; 
        frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build(); // generates a "Frame" object, which can be fed to a face detector
        faces = detector.detect(frame); // detect the faces (detector is a FaceDetector)
        // TODO ... do something with "faces"
    }
```

where `deltaT=1000000/fps`, and `fps` is the desired number of frames per second. For example, if you want to extract 4 frames every second, `deltaT=250000`
(Note that `faces` will be overwritten on every iteration, so you should do something (store/report results) inside the loop

Comment: what is your for loop is doing, kindly elaborate

Comment: The faces, we get are the face detected frames or what it is actually??
and how to deal with them can I convert it to bitmap or can I save it to file!

Comment: you already have bitmaps in `mMMR.getFrameAtTime... ` . So you could just check if `faces` is not empty, and store the bitmaps in a file. That will have the whole frame, but if you want specific faces, the class `Face` has methods to get positions and such within the frame