# Implementing Face Tracking for pre-recorded videos in Android

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-mediacodec, android-vision

I need to implement face detection on mp4 videos, such that the output of my program is a "timeline" indicating the number of faces.

I have looked at the google-vision [examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision) , specifically *photo demo*  and *face Tracker*.

- Following the *photo demo* example, I've created a wrapper which loops over the frames and: 1) extracts thumbnails from the video using `MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime()`, 2) creates frames using `Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build()`, and 3) detects the number of faces with `FaceDetector.detect(frame).size()`. This method works, but it is painfully slow (e.g., 1 second per frame).
- I also looked at the *face tracker* example, which looks a lot more like what I need (and is the suggested approach for videos and camera). The problem here is that the example is tightly associated with the camera.

I also read a similar thread

> [Android Face Detection API - Stored video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019899/android-face-detection-api-stored-video-file)

where the accepted answer looks like my first attempt, but mentions MediaCodec. I've read about it but cant find a way to apply it to my problem (even the examples from bigflake)

As I understand, my options are a) improve the frame extraction step (e.g., using Mediacodec?), or b) mimic the CameraSource functionality but using the mp4 file instead of the actual camera.

Comment: Alternatively you can setup or compile FFMPEG for Android and extract the frames you need into a file, then process them with the `FaceDetector`.

Comment: Yes, there is even an FFMPEG java wrapper available in github somewhere. But working with disk is too slow.
I ended up using the pair `MediaExtractor` + `MediaCodec` to do it in a reasonably fast amount of time, using `ByteBuffer`s. I'll post the code here after some cleaning